# MariaDB remote access ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied

Tags: mysql, mariadb, remote

MariaDB 10.3.27.
Debian 10 Buster.

I've [followed the instructions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/) to grant remote access to a user to my remote MariaDB server:

1. Edited `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`:

   ```
    [mysqld]
    #skip-networking
    #bind-address = <some ip-address>
    skip-networking=0
    skip-bind-address
   ```
2. Created a user:

   ```
    CREATE USER 'theuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'theuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass' WITH GRANT OPTION;
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
    SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user WHERE Host <> 'localhost';
    +---------+------+
    | User    | Host |
    +---------+------+
    | theuser | %    |
    +---------+------+
   ```
3. Restarted MariaDB:

   ```
    $ sudo systemctl restart mariadb
    $ systemctl status mariadb
    ● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.27 database server
       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-05-17 01:00:59 -03; 20min ago
   ```
4. Opened the 3306 port:

   ```
    $ sudo ufw allow 3306/tcp
    $ sudo ufw status | grep 3306
    3306                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
    3306/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
   ```
5. Checked open port locally:

   ```
    $ nmap -p3306 remote_ip
    PORT     STATE SERVICE
    3306/tcp open  mysql
   ```

But when I try to access from my local machine to the remote server:

```
$ mysql -utheuser -pmypass -hremote_ip
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'theuser'@'my_ip' (using password: YES)
```

I'm missing something or there are some errors I can't see?

Comment: Restarting the server and `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` aren't needed.  I tested locally was needed to `drop user ''@localhost;` and then I was able to remotely login. I'm still looking into it.

Comment: Upstream bug lodged [MDEV-25688](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-25688). I'm really hoping, like you, something terribly simple is missed.

Comment: @danblack Thank you! You are going to kill me, but the problem was that my password was not between single quotes. It has a dollar sign `$` in it so the shell doesn't escape it if not between double quotes.

Comment: @danblack I'm using the password in the command right now because I'm managing a couple of servers and multiple passwords...

Comment: Sinle quotes I meant.

Comment: `You are going to kill me,` nah, we've all been there :-) and [shell and sql escaping is a "fun" exercise](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/pull/356) :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was simple, the password in the command line has a special character, the dollar sign `$` which is not escaped by the shell unless in single quotes. So the proper command is:

```
$ mysql -utheuser -p'mypass' -hremote_ip
```

Nonetheless, [security issues are arises when exposing the password in the shell](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/password-security-user.html):

> 6.1.2.1 End-User Guidelines for Password Security
>
> MySQL users should use the following guidelines to keep passwords
> secure.
>
> When you run a client program to connect to the MySQL server, it is
> inadvisable to specify your password in a way that exposes it to
> discovery by other users. The methods you can use to specify your
> password when you run client programs are listed here, along with an
> assessment of the risks of each method. In short, the safest methods
> are to have the client program prompt for the password or to specify
> the password in a properly protected option file.

Comment: not so much "is not escaped", but has a special meaning of being a variable except in a single quoted string. `MYSQL_PWD` environment variable is one way depending on how you use it.